# Strange time ERROR

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\Anmol Jaising\Desktop\Project\File.xml");

        Object[] args1 = new Object[1];



        XmlNodeList nodeActualResultA = xDoc.SelectNodes("/Report/TestScript/Reporter/ReportItems/ReportItem/ActualResult");


        String A = nodeActualResultA[2].InnerText; // 00:04.354



        TimeSpan span = Change(A);
        String spanTime = span.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(A); // 00:04.354
        Console.WriteLine(span); // 00:00.000
        Console.WriteLine(spanTime); // 00:00.000

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public static TimeSpan Change(string span)
    {
        TimeSpan interval;
        TimeSpan.TryParseExact(span, @"mm\.ss\.fff", null, out interval);
        return interval;
    }

}
```

}

If I use time in a simple string format, I get the perfect output. But the moment I convert it to TimeSpan format, whatever may be the time, it comes as 00:00.000
mm:ss.000

Please can you help me?

Comment: Side note: The TryParseExact method has a returns a bool value, indicating whether it could successfully parse a given string or not. It's all written and explained in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784009(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/158761

Answer (score 0):

You write that *A* is equal to *00:04.354*
Thus the TryParseExact requires a format string of

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(span, @"mm\:ss\.fff", null, out interval);
                                  ^
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize that. Thanks a ton for the help :)